# ContentClass for Team Sites

Tags: 2013, search, sharepoint-server

I'm trying to get a list of all site collections through search in the same way I would in SP2010 - i.e. issue a query with

`contentclass:"sts_site"`

This however seems to not pick up all site collections, notably those with the Team Site template.

If I search for these sites by name I can find them, so they're definetly being indexed.

Is there something different I need for these in SP2013?  Or any suggestions of how I can find the contentclass that has actually been applied to the sites in question?

Comment: Try sts_web and see if that returns the site in question

Comment: sts_web doesn't turn up the site either.

Comment: I had faced a similar issue, not exactly the same though. I can faintly recollect that I was not able to retrieve a few site collections and it turned out that the problem was with web titles. Probably it was the special characters in the web title. Can you try to create a couple of test site collections with a simple one-word-name and try retrieving. Sounds wierd but you can attempt !

Comment: Tried this, same issue.  EN-GB settings so no special chars are being used.